# Monitoring a Directory for changes using Python and Watchdog API – how do I capture the file for future operations in a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, file, directory, monitoring, python-watchdog

I have been monitoring a folder using the following Python Code (3.7) with the Watchdog API from PyPI (version 0.8.0) code. I have moved the path to a local folder C:\Dell so I could test the code and it works really well. I want to store the output path in a variable, so I can read the path to determine when a file was created in the target folder.
Eventually, I want to copy that file to another folder for execution on it as well.
Summary:
-   You can tell I’m not a master programmer
-   I have found this Watchdog API that does almost exactly what I need and it prints the src_path to the terminal in test
-   I am trying to create a variable soI can search the string that prints on the terminal to find what change happened, and what file was created
-   If I can get that, I can use this variable to copy the file and manipulate as required.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have tried my best to extract arguments from the sub-processes

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    #path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    path = 'C:\Dell'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

I need a way to get the file path into a variable - preferably a string

Answer (score 1):

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print(event)

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print(event)

    def on_moved(self, event):
        print(event)

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(Handler(), path='/path/to/smth', recursive=True)
observer.start()
```